# Ubuntu 12.04 and Intel/AMD Radeon HD5650

Tags: ati, radeon

Well just wanted to check and see if anyone knows the future for this combo?

Got a laptop atm that runs Win7, but i wanna convert to Ubuntu if possible.
It got the built in Intel gfx aswell as the Radeon HD5650 1gb gfx, i have tried running Fedora on it but the only good solution for saving its life was to use the switcheroo to turn it off.

But i wanna be able to use the HD gfx card since i got it available, as it has been its only generating heat when not turned off.

Answers would be appreciated (1st Q here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your post seems to be a duplicate of this: [How well does an ATI mobility radeon hd 5650 work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34529/how-well-does-an-ati-mobility-radeon-hd-5650-work)

...also a quick google search suggests you should be fine using a newer ubuntu version ie. 11.04 or 11.10 but especially if you're new to ubuntu use the instructions from the link that 'Ryan' provides in his answer.

**EDIT: In your question it reads ubuntu 12.04. This version is in development right now and is supposed to be released in April 2012. If you want to be sure that your laptop works as desired and you want to avoid bugs I'd recommend installing either 11.10 or 11.04 and stay with it til a few weeks after the 12.04 release date.

Comment: Thanks, well using 12.04 on desktop now..rock solid
Will check out some more before changing laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out the [Ubuntu Officially Supported graphics cards list](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware)

Your answer is there.

Comment: Thanks guys, found some guides so will try dualbooting and see if i can install the blob for ATI.