# Ubuntu showing only 256mb of vram when it should be 1GB

Tags: ati, radeon

I'm having serious problems with my ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 (1024mb VRAM). I tried using the "official" proprietary ATI drivers, they bug out the screen and the video card is not even recognized. I'm currently running the default X.org drivers, which recognize it, but only use 256mb of it's VRAM:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Madison [Radeon HD 5000M Series] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device 036d
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
        Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at b4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
        Expansion ROM at b4040000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
        Kernel driver in use: radeon
        Kernel modules: radeon
```

I really notice some lack of video performance due to this fact. Is there any fix out there that can make Ubuntu use the full potential of my card. Please help!

PS: Further info I'm using the latest build of Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Comment: Do these answers help you: http://askubuntu.com/q/34529/236